# Export Access Query to Existing Excel Workbook (which has Macros)

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

First question on Stackoverflow, have been using the site as a viewer for a long time.

I need to export a query from Access 2010 into an existing Excel 2010 Workbook which can be either .xlsm or .xlsb (since macros work in both). I set it up the following way:

- User clicks a button in the Excel workbook to refresh a tab
  --> this runs VBA in Excel that calls a Macro in Access to run
           ---> the macro in Access merely calls an existing query in Access to run and export the results back to the initial Excel Workbook.

Access Macro Code:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "Data_SlotView", "M:\Merch. Strategy\Merch Forecasting\Automotive Division\File Sharing\Automotive Deal-Page-Slot View\Deal-Page-Slot-View.xlsb"
```

My code works if my Excel file was .xlsx but apparently Access 2010 does not allow exporting to Excel files with macros so I have to use some sort of workaround method.

Comment: I just tested and it worked fine for me.  I don't think you need an alternate method; it's better to figure out what's wrong with the one you're trying.  **Are you getting an error?**

Comment: ...also, on what are you basing `"apparently Access 2010 does not allow exporting to Excel files with macros"`?  Did you read that somewhere or is it a guess?

Comment: I don't think that you can "Export to an Excel workbook" if the workbook is currently open, can you?  You should get some file permission or "can't open file" error.

Comment: I thought it could be related that you're exporting to a **`.XLSB`** file (as opposed to `.XLSM`), or that you're using **`acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml`** (as opposed to `acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12`) but I tried various combinations of those and "I couldn't make my test *not* export successfully".  are you sure the filename is correct?

Comment: @ashleedawg No Error it just doesn't export. If I change the file format back to .xlsx it works perfectly fine. I have tried with .xlsm and .xlsb without any luck. And yes, I read it somewhere which linked back to Microsoft's site as the source for the conclusion. I agree, I would love to get this method to work. Did you get it to work using MS 2010 and exporting to a .xlsm file?

Comment: Could you find where you read that?  ...because I think you're mistaken.

Comment: @ashleedawg https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/microsoft-access/425958-docmd-transferspreadsheet-access-2007-excel-2007-xlsm-help-needed.html

Comment: I tested numerous ways, yes. have you tried exporting to a ***different file***?

Comment: @CraigKostka that link doesn't even mention Excel 2010.  The logical next steps for troubleshooting are: 1. Reboot your computer *(could be a file lock problem), 2. Try a different (blank) file, 3. Try exporting a different table.

Comment: @ashleedawg Thanks for your help so far. So I created a .xlsm file on my desktop [Local Disk] and it worked. I then tried to run it from the same folder my initial question is based on [Network Drive] and it also worked BUT I noticed the file now has the file name followed by [Group] displayed in the name of the workbook at the top of the file. This is stored in the same location as the original problem file.

Comment: @craig -  ...but it works?  If you close & re-open, all is okay?  And you can export again?

Comment: @ashleedawg Yes! But the problem file does not update with the [Group] text so I suspect this has something to do with being on a group drive. Thanks for ensuring my code is accurate. I will play around and see if i can get the original file to become similar to the test file i made.

Comment: @craig -  If you continue having problems, you should probably do like Erik suggested below: instead *pushing* from Access, *pull* from Excel.  Did someone else have the file open before?  You shouldn't be exporting to shared files for that reason.  Another option is to export to a "plain" data file, and link your shared workbook from there.

Comment: @ashleedawg The [GROUP] after the file name is not what I believed it to mean. It merely means more than one Excel sheet is selected, as soon as I select only one sheet it disappears. I moved my ORIGINAL file in question to my desktop (Local Drive) it the code still does not run for it. This is really frustrating.

Comment: Did you change the path in your code after you moved the file?

Comment: ...Also, what other code is in the procedure?  For debugging purposes, you should be running only this one line of code. (as per "[mcve]")

Comment: ...I can pretty much guarantee it's a minor oversight on your part, especially since you're "not getting any errors".  Make sure it's the only line of code running (partly so there are no `On Error...` statements running.  Copy and paste the path from your code into a [Start]->[Run] dialog and see if it opens *as is*.  When it opens, scroll to cell A1.

Comment: @ashleedawg I don't think its fair to say that it's guaranteed to be a minor oversight on my part considering I have run this query successfully with other empty .xlsm files and for whatever reason it is not working with the one in question. I have guaranteed the file path is correct as I get it directly from the file and also the code I included is the only code in the Public Function, and there is only one Function I have in the Access file.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using an `INSERT` query from Access:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO [Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=Yes;DATABASE=M:\Merch. Strategy\Merch Forecasting\Automotive Division\File Sharing\Automotive Deal-Page-Slot View\Deal-Page-Slot-View.xlsm].[Sheet1$] SELECT * FROM Data_SlotView;"
```

Comment: Interesting test:... my theory is it won't work because the file transfer method isn't the issue.

Comment: Perhaps. Anyway, the appropriate way, to do it is to import from Excel, instead of exporting to Excel.

Comment: It *should* work either way, but yes.  I'm curious about this one because I've probably used `TransferSpreadsheet` a million times... I was surprised to see that it even works for me if the Excel file is *open*.  I could see the data removed & replaced, as if it was a DB table.  I'm pretty sure *that* didn't used to work.